# Do I have to install visual studio 2010 to make "pip-3.3 install" usable?

Tags: python, pip

I'm using windows7x64, py3.3 x64 on my machine. I get the error：

```
error： Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

This has been an old issue with vs2010 not installed, and I know [***here***](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) I can download most of the binary installers for extension packages. But I still like the `pip install` way which would install the dependencies of some package automatically.

So my question is, what's the *easiest* way solving this problem till now? Do I still have to download&install the huge VS2010 installer?

Comment: I am very interested in this. I feel it is already out of hand. Even with VS2010 installed, a lot of packages just cannot be installed using PIP on Windows without half an hour on Google and messing with compiler and Python configuration. Without Christoph's Unofficial Windows Binaries page it is practically impossible to install packages I routinely use, they usually end up with compiler error of sorts (I have tried PySide on Python 3.4 and Cx_freeze on Python 3.3 recently). I had to install a new computer with Python on a day the web page was down. And basically was not able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to compile source packages (that pip is downloading), then yes, you'll need a compiler of some sort.

For relatively self-contained binary extension packages, setting up a mingw x64 gcc compiler environment might be smaller.

- http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/
- http://drangon.org/mingw/

Note also the [wheel](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wheel) utility can convert python win installers to binary wheels which are installable by pip.

Comment: thx I'll check mingw, will there be inconsistency if some of my packages are compiled with VS9/10 whilst others with MINGW?

Comment: If those rely on binary compatibility between eachother, there could be problems, yes.